# Mutli threading with Threadpool executor and Runnables OR Volley?

Tags: android, android-service, android-volley, threadpoolexecutor

The scenario is like this: The user opens the app and has to take a few photos. The photos have to be uploaded to a server even if the user closes the app.

The app should know about the upload status of the photos when it is open again.

I was thinking of using SQLite to store the status of the photos, so that whenever the app is open it can hit the DB and get to know the status. Additionally, I can have a broadcast receiver which will receive the photo upload status once every photo is uploaded(This is to handle the case when the user does not close the app but he has to be notified of the status, and using a polling mechanism which hits the DB periodically to fetch status info does not seem to be a good approach).

So my question is: Do i create Runnables and manage them using a Thread pool executor OR do is use Volley?

And is Volley even suited for operations where a task should run even after the app is closed?

Comment: Why not use just service which will send broadcast to activity with progress? And it doesn't matter how exactly you will upload photos, with volley, or anything else.

Comment: But if the app is closed then there is no point of sending a broadcast right?

Comment: Not sure that got you. Service will be alive if user will close app. In case if you'd like to notify user about progress via notification panel - you can do it as well from service.

Comment: Yeah via the notification panel will work! I thought you meant sending a broadcast and having a receiver in an activity to receive it.

Comment: Actually, you can do both. When app is activity - you will show progress in activity, when it not active - show via notification panel.

Comment: But will using Volley work? Volley requires a context object to set up a request queue. Once the app is closed or killed the context will not be available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118083/discussion-between-user3282666-and-divers).